# Objective-C and Vector3 struct

Tags: objective-c, struct

I am pretty new to Objective-C (so far I was working with .NET and mainly with ANSI C).

So I am interssted in following:
In .NET I have:

```
struct Vector { float X, float Y ... float Length() .. }
```

But how to manage to do this in Objective-C ?

Using class for Vector3 representation is really dumm, because of huge amount of classes.

I only have Idea do struct in C way and then static class with static methods like `Length(struct Vector3 * vec)`

Is this good way, or way to hell ? And how to do it right-way...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, unless you have a real, actual problem with performance and/or memory usage, define an Objective-C class. Having an Objective-C class will allow you to easily use it in Objective-C collections, property lists, memory management via autorelease pools, and introspection.

That being said, if you have a very simple set of attributes and functions and/or performance/memory are bootlenecks, feel free to use structures and global functions. They’re small and cheap. Apple’s frameworks make use of them — for instance, `NSSize/CGSize` is a simple structure that holds two attributes, width and height, and there are a few functions that operate on them:

```
// structs and typedefs
struct CGSize {
    CGFloat width;
    CGFloat height;
};
typedef struct CGSize CGSize;
typedef CGSize NSSize;

// functions
NSSize NSMakeSize(CGFloat w, CGFloat h);
BOOL NSEqualSizes(NSSize aSize, NSSize bSize);
NSString *NSStringFromSize(NSSize aSize);
…
```

There are other cases in Apple’s frameworks where `struct`s are used instead of classes, e.g. `NSPoint` and `NSRect`.

If you have attributes that are pointers to dynamically allocated memory, you need to be careful with allocation, initialisation, and deallocation. In these cases, an Objective-C class would be more convenient.

An alternative is to use Objective-C++ and make it a C++ class/structure. For instance,

```
struct Vector3 {
    float X;
    float Y;
    float Length() { return X + Y; }
};
```